# Autohotkey: Regex for getting street name in address string

Tags: regex, ms-word, extract, autohotkey

```
65 Gregory Street
;Gregory
141-145 Dickson Road
;Dickson
6B Malvern Avenue
;Malvern
230A John Street
;John
```

I'm trying to extract just the street name in a string, skip the numbers even ones with letters in them and just extract the first word in the string. What's the correct expression for this?

Comment: What program are you using?  perl, python, grep, sed, awk, pcre lib, C/C++, javascript, java, C#?  The exact form [or alternate best way] will vary depending upon the environment you're trying to use it in.

Comment: I'm using Autohotkey to getting customer info from a terminal database and entering it into Microsoft Dynamics. The whole point of getting the Street name is to see if there is another customer in the same street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the first group of non-space characters, get the next non-space group, skip the rest:

```lisp
street := RegExReplace(address, "^\S+ (\S+).*$", "$1")
```

In case of multiline text you can process all lines at once with `m` and `` `a `` options:

```lisp
streets := RegExReplace(addresses, "m`a)^\S+ (\S+).*$", "$1")
```

Use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to test the expressions online.

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very very much! Regex isn't my thing I've just started using it in some of my scripts.